# Удаленное подключение к Firebird

Tags: firebird

Везде говорится что для подключения к firebird, в строке подключения нужно указывать базу данных в формате **<адрес компьютера>:<расположение файла БД на компьютере>**
Неужели к базе данных нельзя подключится зная только адрес, порт и название ДБ (как это реализовано в других СУБД, например MySQL, PostgreSQL)? 
Откуда я могу знать структуру каталогов на чужом компьютере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и не знать. На сервере БД есть специальный файл `aliases.conf`, в котором хранятся сопоставления имени базы данных и пути к файлу где она хранится.

```
# псевдоним = путь/к/файлу.fdb
# База данных 1 (моя 2012)
mydatabase2012 = /opt/firebird/data/filename.fdb
# База данных 2 и 3
mydatabase2 = /opt/firebird/data/otherfile.fdb
mydatabase3 = /home/vasya/firebirddatabases/vasyadbsuperpuper.fdb
```

При подключении к серверу указываете имя пользователя, пароль и псевдоним.